# Painfully slow transfer speed on Dropbox App folder compared to public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

Accessing images that are in the public Dropbox folder with static urls are very fast to download and is a viable solution for image hosting on a webpage.

To be able to dynamically add/remove images I've tried to use their API through the gem [carrierwave-dropbox](https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox).

All actions work functionally but it's dreadfully slow, often several seconds for each image to download. I don't know the cause for this but I don't want anything of it.

Is it possible to use Dropbox API and get the same snappy speed a file saved in the public folder provides, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe get the the urls of the images to download via the api/gem and then fetch the images outside of the gem?

Comment: Also, if you're having to fetch a list of images to download it's going to have to parse the directory for whatever files you need adding run time

Comment: When using the API, the URL are expiring every 4 hours, so I'd love to not use the API. But I'm not sure it works. When installing the gem I read that there are two different Dropbox apps: https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox/wiki/Access-types But I cannot find in the Dropbox docs that it's still the case.

Comment: Gotcha. I would maybe just use whatever technique you find most appropriate to gather the urls of the images you want to use and subsequently use whatever mean you think is fastest to download the images